# Sparx EA: create custom table while generating RTF

Tags: rtf, enterprise-architect, documentation-generation

Is there are way by SparxEA's Document Generation tools create custom tables?

**Problem**:

Inside model, I got packages. Inside every `package` could be one/few `diagrams`.
In every `diagram` could be `Notes` with text, from which I need to build tables(!).

I know that I can call `template fragment` from script (which called from other `template fragment` etc)  like this

```
var documentGenerator = Repository.CreateDocumentGenerator();
documentGenerator.DocumentPackage(packageId, 9, "myFragment");
```

or use also something like this

```
documentGenerator.DocumentElement(elementId, 9, "myOtherFragment");
```

or any other function described here http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/9.3/automation/document_generator_interface_class.html

and it would invoked our template, with described specfifc fileds or even determinated table (with constant coulmn names and count) inside

but...

**Question**

Is there any specific way of **create custom tables** (we couldnt know count of columns, we dont know names etc until we will process, as I mentioned above, `diagram.Notes`) **while doing RTF documentation generation** inside Sparx EA architect?

**UPD 31.01.2017**

So, the only way today is to build rtf generator by your own. 
Currently I am on it - building very simple RTF generator just to output table data. 
Decided to close the question for now, but will update it in future due to current progress on RTF scripting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to create really custom tables is to use the new *(v12.1?)* **Document Script** template fragment
With this type of fragment you have to call a script that returns raw RTF.

Seems best if you try to find some kind of RTF library to use, because writing RTF from scratch seems quite complex.

Comment: Well, I got sparx ea v13. 
`With this type of fragment you have to call a script that returns raw RTF.`
Oh, well, that interesting!

Comment: Is there are way to use any third-party library in Sparx EA? Just include'em in files?

Comment: And how we suppose to return raw rtf?
Just instead of `documentGenerator .GetDocumentAsRTF()` return something like `{\rtf1\ansi\deff0 {\fonttbl {\f0 Times New Roman;}}
\f0\fs60 Hello, World!
}` ?

Comment: You can use any library known in COM. There are a few examples that use .Net xml libraries and stuff like that in order to create xml files. But basically yes, the script has to return code RTF code like that.

Comment: Thanks, mr. Bellekens! Trying to write simple rtf table constructor in Jscript atm. Kinda tricky, but nothing really complex there, as I see. If I will achieve something which is could be helpful (at least for me) I would update question